# Find all offsetCells after specific key word?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, find

This is the code i have, but at the line containing the .FindNext expression runtime error 438 shows up. Where is the problem?

```
Dim bottomCell As Range
Dim offsetCell As Range
With Sheets("C7BB2HD3IINA_NRM_X302")
    Set bottomCell = .Cells.Find(what:="KENNFELD")
    Set offsetCell = bottomCell.Offset(0, 1)
    Set offsetCell = .FindNext(offsetCells)
End With
```

Comment: `FindNext` is method of a `Range` object; by virtue of your `With...End With` construct, you are calling it as if it were a `Worksheet` method, which it isn't

Comment: Also - `FindNext(offsetCells)` you have not declared any variable `offsetCells`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Find/FindNext is complex enough that you should split it out into a separate function which just returns the matches.  That way you can focus on the main logic instead of getting tangled up in the `Find` process.

Try this:

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    Dim col As Collection, c
    
    Set col = FindAll(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("C7BB2HD3IINA_NRM_X302").Cells, _
                       "KENNFELD", xlWhole) 'or xlPart
    
    For Each c In col 'loop over matches
        MsgBox c.Offset(0, 1).Value
    Next c

End Sub


'Find all matches for `val` in `rng` and return as a Collection of cells
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val As String, matchType As XlLookAt) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    
    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.CountLarge), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=matchType, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Hey thank you very much for your time. But iz says "col As dcollection" type is not defined, in the error message

Comment: Sorry typo - `Dim col as Collection`

Comment: I dont know what it is, but your code does not work. Error with line Next

Comment: Remove the `d` from `Next d`, it looks like a typo.

Comment: Still does not work after that. Error 6 at line Set f = rng.Find

Comment: `rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count)` >> `rng.Cells(rng.Cells.CountLarge)` I guess I never tested that function with a whole worksheet....